# Reflective subcategory of a complete category

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to understand why the reflective subcategory of a complete category is complete. Let $\mathcal{C}\subset \mathcal{D}$ with $\mathcal{D}$ complete and let $r:\mathcal{D}\to \mathcal{C}$ be the reflection. Consider the cone $(\lim X_k \to (X_k)_k)$ where all $X_k\in \mathcal{C}$. Each canonical map $\lim X_k \to X_k$ for each $k$ gives rise to the factorization $\lim X_k \to r(\lim X_k) \to X_k$ for any $k$, and since the factorization is unique, we get a new cone $(r(\lim X_k) \to (X_k)_k)$. Then each cone $(Y \to (X_k)_k)$ gives rise to the factorization $(Y \to \lim X_k \to r(\lim X_k) \to (X_k)_k)$. Why is the map $Y\to r(\lim X_k)$ unique ? I must use somewhere that the right adjoint of $r$ (the inclusion $\mathcal{C}\subset \mathcal{D}$) is full and faithful of course. Any help ? I cannot find the proof in the books I have with me. Thanks.

Comment: Where does the factorisation $\lim X_k \to r(\lim X_k) \to X_k$ come from? It's the counit that's an isomorphism here, not the unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't just proving that $\mathcal C$ is complete, you know that it's complete in a specific way, ie. that limits are calculated the same way both in $\mathcal C$ and in $\mathcal D$, or in other words, that the canonical map $η : \lim X → r \lim X$ must be an isomorphism. (This is because the inclusion, being by assumption right adjoint, must preserve limits.)
If you prove that, the cone $(ρ_k : r(\lim X) → X_k)_k$ you already constructed will be isomorphic to the limiting cone $(π_k : \lim X → X_k)_k$, and so limiting itself.

Getting the inverse of $η$ is easy, because $ρ$ must factor through $π$ via a unique $\mathcal D$-morphism $ϑ$. From $π_kϑ = ρ_k$ and $ρ_kη = π_k$ one gets $π_kϑη = π_k$ for all $k$, and so $ϑη = \mathrm{id}$ by the universality of $π$. Since $\mathcal C$ is full, $ηϑ$ is a $C$-morphism, and by $ηϑη = η$ and the universality of $η$, it's the identity morphism too.

As a sidenote, a short non-elementary way to prove this is to note that the inclusions of full subcategories are monadic, and therefore create all limits.

Comment: "Every monadic functor creates limits". References for this interesting fact and thank you for the answer.

Comment: It is enough to prove that the forgetful functor from Eilenberg-Moore category creates limits, which is not too hard: if $α_k : TA_k → A_k$ are algebras in your diagram, then $α_k$'s induce a morphism $\lim α : T\lim A → \lim A$, which ought to be the limit. You can find the proof in Mac Lane, Borceux's Handbook of Categorical Algebra, The Joy of Cats, and probably many other places. Similarly, monadic functors create every colimit preserved by T and TT.