# The kernel of a morphism of presheaves

Tags: category-theory

I am following a course on category theory, following the notes of Shapira "Algebra and topology". If $P, Q$ are presheaves $P, Q: OP_X^{op} \to Mod(k)$ and $\phi: P \to Q$ a morphism of presheaves, there is that $ker(\phi(U)) = ker(\phi)(U)$. How can this be proved?

I thought of using the definition of kernels with $Hom(Y,ker\phi) = ker(Hom(Y,P) \rightrightarrows
 Hom(Y,Q))$, but this did not worked out.

I saw that similar questions has already been asked, for instance [On kernels and stalks of sheaves.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4817311/on-kernels-and-stalks-of-sheaves), but there they define $ker (\phi)(U) = ker (\phi(U))$. This confuses me, since $ker \phi$ is a functor $OP_X^{op} \to Mod(k)$, so $ker (\phi)(U)$ already has a meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Limits in functor categories are computed pointwise: given categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, where $\mathcal{D}$ has the necessary limits, and given a diagram $\mathcal{I}\to\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}), i\mapsto F_i$, we have that $\mathrm{lim}_{\mathcal{I}} \,F_i$ exists and satisfies $(\mathrm{lim}_\mathcal{I}\,F_i)(c)\cong \mathrm{lim}_\mathcal{I}\,F_i(c)$ for all $c\in\mathcal{C}$. So given a diagram $0,\phi\colon P\rightrightarrows Q$, where one arrow is $\phi$ and the other is $0$, the limit of this diagram (which by definition is the presheaf $\mathrm{ker}(\phi)$), satisfies $(\mathrm{ker}(\phi))(U)\cong\mathrm{lim}(0,\phi_U\colon P(U)\rightrightarrows Q(U))\cong:\mathrm{ker}(\phi(U))$ for every open $U$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement you are trying to prove concerns the relationship between the kernels of morphisms of presheaves and the kernels of the induced morphisms on the sections of the presheaves.

Given presheaves $ P, Q $ on $ \text{OP}_X^\text{op} $ with values in the category of $ k $-modules $ \text{Mod}(k) $ and a morphism of presheaves $ \phi: P \rightarrow Q $, the kernel of $ \phi $, denoted $ \text{ker}(\phi) $, is itself a presheaf. For each open set $ U \subseteq X $, $ \text{ker}(\phi)(U) $ is the kernel of the morphism $ \phi(U): P(U) \rightarrow Q(U) $ in the category $ \text{Mod}(k) $.

To show that $ \text{ker}(\phi)(U) = \text{ker}(\phi(U)) $, you need to understand that:

1. $ \text{ker}(\phi)(U) $ is defined as the set of sections $ s \in P(U) $ such that $ \phi(U)(s) = 0 $ in $ Q(U) $.
2. $ \text{ker}(\phi(U)) $ is the kernel of the morphism $ \phi(U) $ in the category $ \text{Mod}(k) $, which is the module of elements $ s \in P(U) $ such that $ \phi(U)(s) = 0 $.

Since both descriptions are essentially the same, it follows directly from the definitions that $ \text{ker}(\phi)(U) = \text{ker}(\phi(U)) $. This is true because both are describing the same submodule of $ P(U) $, consisting of those elements that are sent to zero under the morphism $ \phi(U) $.

This can be summarized in the category theory language by noting that the kernel functor is a left exact functor, which means it preserves finite limits, including kernels. Therefore, the kernel of the natural transformation $ \phi $ (viewed as a morphism between functors $ P $ and $ Q $) should be given pointwise by the kernels of the morphisms $ \phi(U) $ for each $ U $.

To formalize this in a proof, you would use the definitions of kernels in the category of modules, the fact that presheaves are functors, and the way natural transformations between functors correspond to morphisms between these functors when evaluated at each object in the domain category.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a very confused answer, which also just assumes that the result OP wants proven is true, thus missing the point of the question.  Statements that the kernel functor is left exact are not relevant to the question. Given that you have produced 6 somewhat longer answers to various questions within the span of half an hour, while having said in 3 of them that ChatGPT wrote them, I will ask you this: did you use ChatGPT also for the other 3, including this one? Because to me, it seems like this answer here was written by it.